# Saving in database entity with 2 oneToMany relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i explain my problem, asking sorry for my english!
I have 2 entity: Projects and Operations. Each projects can have more operations, each operation can have different price. 
So, i have created a new entity ProgettoOperazionePrezzo

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="prezzo", type="decimal")
 */
private $prezzo;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set prezzo
 *
 * @param float $prezzo
 * @return ProgettoOperazionePrezzo
 */
public function setPrezzo($prezzo)
{
    $this->prezzo = $prezzo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get prezzo
 *
 * @return float 
 */
public function getPrezzo()
{
    return $this->prezzo;
}


 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Progetto")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="progetto_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $progetto;

/**
 * Set progetto
 *
 * @param \Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\Progetto $progetto
 * @return ProgettoOperazionePrezzo
 */
public function setProgetto(\Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\Progetto $progetto = null)
{
    $this->progetto = $progetto;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get progetto
 *
 * @return \Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\Progetto 
 */
public function getProgetto()
{
    return $this->progetto;
}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Operazione")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="operazione_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $operazione;

/**
 * Set operazione
 *
 * @param \Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\Operazione $operazione
 * @return ProgettoOperazionePrezzo
 */
public function setOperazione(\Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\Operazione $operazione = null)
{
    $this->operazione = $operazione;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get operazione
 *
 * @return \Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\Operazione 
 */
public function getOperazione()
{
    return $this->operazione;
}
```

Now i want create a form to save in database all the operations that i chose with checkbutton.

```
 $operazione =   new ProgettoOperazionePrezzo();
    $progetto   =   $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ManagementProgettiBundle:ProgettoOperazionePrezzo')->find($id_progetto);

    $form       =   $this->createFormBuilder($operazione)
                          ->add('operazione','entity',array(
            'label'=>'Operazioni da effettuare:',
            'multiple'=>true,
            'expanded'=>true,
            'class'=>'ManagementProgettiBundle:Operazione',
            'property'=>'nome',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) 
                               {
                                   return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                              ->orderBy('u.nome', 'ASC');
                               }))
                             ->add('Passo successivo','submit');
    $form->handleRequest($request);
 if($form->isValid()){

                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $operazione->setProgetto($progetto);
                    $em->persist($operazione);
                    $em->flush();

                    //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('management_progetti_nuovo_progetto_p3',array('id_progetto'=>$id_progetto)));

             }
```

I have no problem to show the form...but it dwsnt works when i try to save in database my choices cause it give me this error:

`Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\ProgettoOperazionePrezzo::setOperazione() must be an instance of Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\Operazione, instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\alemanno_management\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php on line 345 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\alemanno_management\src\Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\ProgettoOperazionePrezzo.php line 108`

What am i doing of wrong?!!?maybe all??please...can u tell me how can i resolve this?!

Answer (score 0):

Because you fetch multiple results from database, your `$progetto` variable will contain an instance of ArrayCollection, over which you should iterate. Because your query contains an id which should be unique, I assume that you want to fetch only one results:

```
$progetto   =   $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ManagementProgettiBundle:ProgettoOperazionePrezzo')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id_progetto));
```

Now your `$progetto` variable should point to an instance of `Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\Operazione`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next entity, please:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="prezzo", type="decimal")
 */
private $prezzo;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set prezzo
 *
 * @param float $prezzo
 * @return ProgettoOperazionePrezzo
 */
public function setPrezzo($prezzo)
{
    $this->prezzo = $prezzo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get prezzo
 *
 * @return float 
 */
public function getPrezzo()
{
    return $this->prezzo;
}


 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Progetto")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="progetto_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $progetto;


/**
 * Set progetto
 *
 * @param \Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\Progetto $progetto
 * @return ProgettoOperazionePrezzo
 */
public function setProgetto(\Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\Progetto $progetto = null)
{
    $this->progetto = $progetto;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get progetto
 *
 * @return \Management\ProgettiBundle\Entity\Progetto 
 */
public function getProgetto()
{
    return $this->progetto;
}

public function __construct() {
    $this->operazione = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Operazione")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="operazione_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $operazione;

/**
 * Set operazione
 *
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $operazione
 * @return ProgettoOperazionePrezzo
 */
public function setOperazione(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $operazione = null)
{
    $this->operazione = $operazione;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get operazione
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection 
 */
public function getOperazione()
{
    return $this->operazione;
}
```